# PHP if statement within a fetched array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code that generates the below table thru an AJAX request sent from the same page.

The `mysql` query fetches the data within a range of 7 days from "today".

The fetched data gets appended to the table's tbody as shown In the first screenshot below.

My Code Is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM `BIMTECH_academy_2016_classes` 
WHERE `RealDate` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER BY RealDate ASC, RealFrom ASC; ");

    $html = ""; // a variable
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $html.= "<tr>";
          $html.= "<td colspan='4' id='date'>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
      $html.= "</tr>";
      $html.= "</tr>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['CourseName'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['From'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['To'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['InstructorName'] . "</td>";
          //$html.= "<td>" . $row['ClassNumber'] . "</td>";
      $html.= "</tr>";
    }
```

[image]

Results are all correct, however, What I am trying to do is getting red of the duplicated date(s) as shown in the second screenshot below.

[image]

Moreover I  need to add to the table the other days that has no content so I finally see seven days in the table (some with data, and others without "off days")

**Any Ideas ??**

Comment: You can save your data into `array()` _(for example)_ as first and then you can create HTML from this array (foreach). Then you can filter the same dates from array and highlight them with red color.

Answer (score 1):

Should do what u want

```
$result = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM `BIMTECH_academy_2016_classes` 
WHERE `RealDate` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER BY RealDate ASC, RealFrom ASC; ");

    $html = ""; // a variable
    $lastDate;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($lastDate != $row['Date'])
        {
              $lastDate = $row['Date'];
              $html.= "<tr>";
                  $html.= "<td colspan='4' id='date'>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
              $html.= "</tr>";
        }
      $html.= "<tr>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['CourseName'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['From'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['To'] . "</td>";
          $html.= "<td>" . $row['InstructorName'] . "</td>";
          //$html.= "<td>" . $row['ClassNumber'] . "</td>";
      $html.= "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Monarchis, what about the other objective I am trying to achieve? Any Ideas

Comment: `Moreover I need to add to the table the other days that has no content so I finally see seven days in the table (some with data, and others without "off days")`